# Deleting dynamically sized array from function

Tags: c++, return-value, dynamic-allocation

In this part of my code (receiving the time) I have a dynamically sized array of chars. This is for a school project and dynamically sized arrays are required.

```
char* msgtime::getTime() {

    std::string t;
    t.append(std::to_string(hour));
    t.append(":");
    t.append(std::to_string(minute));

    char *charTime = new char[t.length()];
    strcpy(charTime, t.c_str());

    return charTime;
}
```

However, I can't delete the charTime since I am returning the value. I tried following another question I saw on here to return it into a char* in the main program then delete that when I'm done with it. The code here is what the function is returning to:

```
void receive(packet &data, SOCKET con) {
    msgtime tim;

    cout << "Receiving data" << endl;
    int in = recv(con, (char*)&data, sizeof(data), 0);
    cout << "Data received: " << in << endl;

    tim.updateTime();
    char *newTime = tim.getTime();
    strcpy(data.time, newTime);
    delete[] newTime;

}
```

Except when I run it I get this error:

HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#183) at 0x00129330
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after the end of heap buffer.

I need to delete the charTime in the getTime function to plug the memory leak but I can't figure out how to do it. Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: *"This is for a school project and dynamically sized arrays are required."* Your teacher may or may not know that, but the standard runtime-sized array in C++ is `std::vector`. Please avoid all `operator new[]` business.

Comment: Please, please, *please* just use smart pointers and/or standard container classes instead of manual memory management and keep your sanity..

Comment: @BaummitAugen vectors aren't covered in the curriculum for this class

Comment: @BryceThompson You may want to consider supplementing your class with a good C++ book then, so you don't end up learning 90s C++ in 2017.

Comment: @Bryce Thompson "vectors aren't covered in the curriculum" that doesn't mean you can't read up on them on your own. Why insist on stupid code when better alternatives exist?

Comment: I am planning on learning vectors but dynamic allocation is required in the project.

Comment: use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and if someone asks where the dynamically sized array is, then show them [`std::string::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)

Comment: You already use `std::string` BTW, and even if you couldn't, you may rewrite a `mystring` once and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't allocate enough space, one more char is required to store null terminator:

```
char *charTime = new char[t.length() + 1];
```

Comment: That said, why don't you just return `std::string` directly?

Comment: yep, that did it. stupid mistake on my part but im so glad it works now! i ran visual leak detector and now it works fine, thanks a bunch :)